# Server control in mark-up, but without the instance being created

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

**Summary**

Is it possible to have a server-side control that does NOT create an instance of the control on the page load, without using `<asp:PlaceHolder>`?

*Edit, despite the example code being in C#, I've added VB.NET as a tag, as I believe this is a question that is ASP.NET specific, rather than just C#*

**Details**

In an .aspx page (in an ASP.NET web application under .NET 4.0), I would like to have the following code...

```
<%if (m_myVar) {%>
<uc1:MyControl1 runat="server" id="myCtrl1"/>
<%}%>
```

But I don't want the system to create an instance of `MyControl1` if `m_myVar == false`

The obvious solution is to use a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control, and create an instance in the code...

```
protected MyControl1 myCtrl1 = null;

if (m_myVar)
{
   myCtrl1 = (MyControl1)Page.LoadControl(@"~/MyControl1.ascx");
   myPlacehHolder.Controls.Add(myCtrl1);
}
```

I'm just wondering if there is an inbuilt way to do this, so that the `<asp:PlaceHolder>` method is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do something like this (pardon the VB):

```
   If m_myVar
       For Each c In Page.Controls
                If TypeOf c Is HtmlForm Then
                    Dim ctrl As New MyControl1
                    c.Controls.Add(ctrl)
                End If
       Next
   End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't really help - as it gives no ability to position the control within the structure

Comment: Yeah, if you want that without creating the control on page_load you're gonna have to use a placeholder.